# What package is this: from schemas.tokens import Token

Tags: python

In [this](https://www.fastapitutorial.com/blog/authentication-in-fastapi/) tutorial one line of the code reads

```
from schemas.tokens import Token
```

Which package do I need to install? I cannot find it out by Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further down the tutorial we read:

> We need a schema to verify that we are returning an access_token and token_type as defined in our response_model. Let's put this code in schemas > tokens.py

So it's a package created in the tutorial itself, i.e. a custom package, not from some library.

Answer (score 0):

yeah. thats the problem.

if you've read the entire tutorial, you would see this tree structure

```sh
backend/
├─.env
├─apis/
│ └─general_pages/
│   └─route_homepage.py
├─core/
│ └─config.py
├─db/
│ ├─base.py
│ ├─base_class.py
│ ├─models/
│ │ ├─jobs.py
│ │ └─users.py
│ └─session.py
├─main.py
├─requirements.txt
├─schemas/          # <---------------- HERE
│ ├─jobs.py         
│ └─users.py        
├─static/
│ └─images/
│   └─logo.png
└─templates/
  ├─components/
  │ └─navbar.html
  ├─general_pages/
  │ └─homepage.html
  └─shared/
    └─base.html
```

where schemas is package inside root project